# Is it possible to detect when the "Minute" changes on the status bar clock?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have a complex problem to describe so Ill save it and just sum up what im trying to do. I am looking to "get notified" when the time on the status bar changes so I can recalculate time till. I am currently calculating time till just fine, but there is that 1 minute window where my calculations and where the time stamp wont match... it all depends on when they opened the app, compared to where the iPhone "seconds" clock was when they opened it.

So in short, can we detect when the minute changes on the status bar? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I'd do:

When the app launches, I'd start a timer that would update every second to check when the time changes.

The first time I find a time change, I'd invalidate that timer and start one that would fire every minute.

This minute timer would be in sync with a delay no greater than a second with the clock on the status bar.

Answer (score 13):

Even simpler than Emilio's answer - when your view loads (or when you want to trigger the event) just check the seconds portion of current date (eg. with NSCalendar), schedule a timer that will fire in 60-currentSeconds (that will be the next minute, zero seconds) and finally, schedule new timer that fires each 60 seconds.

Comment: This is the smartest answer.

Comment: This worked for me but I had to do 61-currentSeconds

Answer (score 7):

Based on @mja's suggestion:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger currentSecond = [components second];

//+1 to ensure we fire right after the minute change
NSDate *fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60 - currentSecond + 1];
NSTimer *timer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:fireDate
                                          interval:60
                                            target:self
                                          selector:@selector(YOURSELECTORHERE)
                                          userInfo:nil
                                           repeats:YES];

[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

I'm using it and it works great.  You'll have to be more careful if you need to ever remove the timer.

Answer (score 5):

Based on @SG1 code sample but in Swift:

```
// Calculate fireDate on every minute's first second
let now: Date = Date()
let calendar: Calendar = Calendar.current
let currentSeconds: Int = calendar.component(.second, from: now)

// Init timer
self.timer = Timer(
    fire: now.addingTimeInterval(Double(60 - currentSeconds + 1)),
    interval: 60 /*seconds*/,
    repeats: true,
    block: { (t: Timer) in
        self.sendNotification()
    })

// Start timer
RunLoop.main.add(self.timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)

private func sendNotification(){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I dug into this and found the `Calendar.nextDate(after:matching:matchingPolicy:repeatedTimePolicy:direction:)` method, removing the need for doing any calculations in app code at all.

Example:

```swift
var zeroSeconds = DateComponents()
zeroSeconds.second = 0
guard let nextMinute = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).nextDate(after: Date(), matching: zeroSeconds, matchingPolicy: .nextTime, direction: .forward) else {
  // This should not happen since there should always be a next minute
  return
}

let timer = Timer(fire: nextMinute.advanced(by: 0.1), interval: 60, repeats: true) { _ in
  // This runs at every turn of a minute
}

RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .default)
```

As other answers note, some buffer seems to be necessary to make sure this gets fired after the minute has turned (vital if you're presenting the time every minute for example), hence the  `nextMinute.advanced(by: 0.1)` (100 ms). I haven't found any documentation on exactly how much, but the 100 ms seems OK in my brief testing.

Comment: This is work perfectly for me, where do you found the documentation? cause I don't understand how this works

Comment: In my opinion, this is the most precise answer. Great job 

Comment: @FarrasDoko How it works is it creates a `Date` object representing the next minute change (i.e., the next date with seconds == 0). Then it creates a timer to fire on that `Date` (well, plus 0.1 seconds to ensure it isn't missed in the case this method was called right on the turn of the minute), and then fire every 60 seconds thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to trigger a Timer using `scheduledTimer`, this approach uses a function that recurrently calls itself once the timer gets fired instead of using a fixed 60s intervals.

```swift
private var timer: Timer?

private func setupTimer() {
    let calendar: Calendar = .current
    let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from: Date())
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
        withTimeInterval: 60 - TimeInterval(seconds), repeats: false
    ) { [weak self] timer in
        self?.timer = nil
        // Do something, eg. update UI
        self?.setupTimer()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such notification, so I guess you need to write some code that polls the time fairly often. I would create a run loop source for this, add it to the common modes and let it check if the current `NSTimerInterval` since your favorite reference date is greater or equal to some pre-calculated `NSTimeInterval` that contains the time interval for the next full minute.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @stefanlindbohm's answer but without a strong reference to `self` and stopping the timer at next firing if the object has been deallocated:

```swift
var zeroSeconds = DateComponents()
zeroSeconds.second = 0
guard let nextMinute = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).nextDate(after: Date(), matching: zeroSeconds, matchingPolicy: .nextTime, direction: .forward) else {
    // This should not happen since there should always be a next minute
    return
}

var timer: Timer?
timer = Timer(fire: nextMinute.advanced(by: 0.1), interval: 60, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
    guard let self = self else {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        return
    }

    // Do your work here, using `self`.
}

if let timer = timer {
    RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .default)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a SwiftUI ViewModel that will publish the current time every minute when the minute value changes. This could be easily modified to post a notification for app wide updates.

```
final class TimeChangeViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var time = Date()
private var timer: Timer?

init() {
    setInitialTimer()
}

deinit {
    timer?.invalidate()
}

private func setInitialTimer() {
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: Date())
    let currentSecondsValue = components.second ?? 0
    let secondsUntilNextMinute: TimeInterval = TimeInterval(60 - currentSecondsValue)
    
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: secondsUntilNextMinute, repeats: false, block: { _ in
        self.updateTime()
        self.setOneMinuteUpdateTimer()
    })
}

private func setOneMinuteUpdateTimer() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 60, repeats: true, block: { _ in
        self.updateTime()
    })
    
    timer?.tolerance = 0.5
}

private func updateTime() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.time = Date()
        // could post a custom notification here...
    }
}
```

}